# Finding opening and closing parentheses in an input field, delete them (together with everything inside)?

Tags: jquery

I would like to accomplish the following with jQuery: find an opening and closing parenteshes in the input field with the ID of `#post_tag_names` and remove them from he input field (together with the content inside the parentheses).

For example, if the input field has this:

```
rails (30)
```

it should end up like this:

```
rails
```

How to accomplish that?

**EDIT**

I already have the triggering event:

```
$('#post_tag_names').bind('railsAutocomplete.select', function(event, data){
  /* I NEED THIS PART */
});
```

Comment: do you also want to remove () or just (something)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$input.val( $input.val().replace(/\(.+\)/, '') );
```

Comment: shouldn't you use .val() for a textbox?

Comment: not being a regex expert whats the difference between .+ and .*

Comment: `*` matches 0 or more. `+` matches 1 or more

Comment: it should be more specific to his binding this would affect all inputs no?

Comment: nah, `$input` is just whatever he wants, in this case I assume `#post_tag_names`. Its better with the `g` global in your example but why the capturing group?

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplest way to do it but you need to figure-out where you get the value. If its from data or part of your data then replace it with RegEx:
[Here is the sample](http://jsfiddle.net/RnZsU/1/)

Answer (score 0):

how about Plain old javascript.

```
jQuery('#post_tag_names').bind('railsAutocomplete.select', function(event, data){
    jQuery(this).val(jQuery(this).val().replace(/\((.*)\)/g, ""));
});
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use regular expressions,

```
    var input=$('#post_tag_names');
    input.val(input.val().replace(/[\(\)0-9]/i, ""));
```

Comment: he said jquery and gave class names. he wants to pull the value dynamically from a textbox

Comment: this is still not correct. as it will not affect the input box.