# Removing parentheses in an input field, the text between them and the space before them?

Tags: jquery

In this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9597463/finding-opening-and-closing-parentheses-in-an-input-field-delete-them-together/9597893#9597893), I asked how to remove parenteshes and the text inside them. Got this:

```
$(this).val($(this).val().replace(/\(.+\)/, ''));
```

So this: `food (454)` becomes this: `food`

This works fine but now I would like to not only remove the parentheses and the text between them but also to remove the space before the parentheses.

In the example above, the space I'm talking about would be the space between the letter `d` and the `(`

How to modify the code so that it can accomplish that?

Comment: Add the space to the expression.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit Duh! Just figured out that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No jquery needed at all!

```
this.value = this.value.replace(/\s+\(.+?\)/g, '');
```

[**Live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8VS9B/6/)

Credit to @AnthonyGrist!

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, I forgot to mention that there is this scenario too: `tag1 tag1 (23)` too. Right now, your code does this: `tag1` to that and I looking for this: `tag1 tag1`.

Comment: You need to escape the parantheses in the regular expression using the `\\` (backslash).

Comment: @AnthonyGrist. You're right! but that doesn't work, why? see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8VS9B/5/)

Comment: You have a greedy match, so having more than one set of parentheses matches all of the content between the `(` of the first set and the `)` of the last set. Also, this may or may not be intentional, but there's no space before the first parenthesis, so the expression matches nothing. See [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8VS9B/6/) and click on the input.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist. But this one didn't delete `bar(32)`. it deletes only the first match.

Comment: @gdoron That's intentional. As I pointed out in my previous comment, the regular expression is only intended to match content in parentheses that are preceded by a space, which isn't the case for `bar(32)` - `bar (32)`, on the other hand, would be deleted (or, rather, the ` (32)` part would be).

Comment: @AnthonyGrist. Right, I forgot what was the question about... lol. Gave you the credit for the update. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.trim($(this).val($(this).val().replace(/\(.+\)/, '')));
```

Comment: Strange, for some reason I'm still getting that space in that input field.

Comment: Why are you using jquery to get the value?! `this.value` will bring you the value!

Comment: @ubercooluk If you're going to add additional code to your answer, edit the answer rather than putting badly formatted code into a comment.